# Bring back sibling values within a parent node

Tags: c#, xml, linq-to-xml

```
<po-response xmlns="http://test.com/oms/v3" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="rest/oms/export/v3/purchase-order.xsd">
  <!--Generated on host [spapp403p.prod.ch4.s.com]-->
  <purchase-order>
    <customer-order-confirmation-number>335342876</customer-order-confirmation-number>
    <customer-email>123456@test.com</customer-email>
    <po-number>12345</po-number>
    <po-date>2012-02-29</po-date>
    <po-time>13:02:59</po-time>
    <po-number-with-date>201202292988262</po-number-with-date>
    <unit>9301</unit>
    <site>Test</site>
    <channel>VD</channel>
    <location-id>1234</location-id>
    <expected-ship-date>2013-06-05</expected-ship-date>
    <shipping-detail>
      <ship-to-name>JOHN DOH</ship-to-name>
      <address>1234 MADE UP LANE</address>
      <city>BLAH</city>
      <state>KK</state>
      <zipcode>1234</zipcode>
      <phone>666123456</phone>
      <shipping-method>Ground</shipping-method>
    </shipping-detail>
    <customer-name>JOHN DOH</customer-name>
    <po-line>
      <po-line-header>
        <line-number>3</line-number>
        <item-id>ABC-12345</item-id>
        <item-name>Professional Chrome Dumbbell 1</item-name>
        <selling-price-each>12.76</selling-price-each>
        <commission>1.52</commission>
        <order-quantity>2</order-quantity>
        <shipping-and-handling>12.66</shipping-and-handling>
      </po-line-header>
      <po-line-detail>
        <po-line-status>NEW</po-line-status>
        <quantity>2</quantity>
      </po-line-detail>
    </po-line>
    <po-line>
      <po-line-header>
        <line-number>2</line-number>
        <item-id>BCD-33022</item-id>
        <item-name>Professional Chrome Dumbbell 2</item-name>
        <selling-price-each>13.82</selling-price-each>
        <commission>1.14</commission>
        <order-quantity>2</order-quantity>
        <shipping-and-handling>18.66</shipping-and-handling>
      </po-line-header>
      <po-line-detail>
        <po-line-status>NEW</po-line-status>
        <quantity>2</quantity>
      </po-line-detail>
    </po-line>
    <po-line>
      <po-line-header>
        <line-number>1</line-number>
        <item-id>CDE-33021</item-id>
        <item-name>Professional Chrome Dumbbell 3</item-name>
        <selling-price-each>15.88</selling-price-each>
        <commission>1.76</commission>
        <order-quantity>2</order-quantity>
        <shipping-and-handling>18.68</shipping-and-handling>
      </po-line-header>
      <po-line-detail>
        <po-line-status>NEW</po-line-status>
        <quantity>1</quantity>
      </po-line-detail>
    </po-line>
    <order-total-sell-price>42.92</order-total-sell-price>
    <total-commission>1.42</total-commission>
    <total-shipping-handling>46.00</total-shipping-handling>
    <balance-due>67.50</balance-due>
    <sales-tax>15.13</sales-tax>
    <po-status>New</po-status>
  </purchase-order>
<purchase-order>
.
.
.
```

I need a way to bring back all the details within the  in particular I'm having a issue as there can be any number of  's in the case above there is three of them and i need to loop through these within the  and then move onto the next.

I was using the following code using XDcoument which worked fine with only one po-line but but can't get it to work with more than one.

```
xmlDoc = XDocument.Parse(sr.ReadToEnd());
XNamespace ns = "http://test.com/oms/v3";
var purchaseOrders = from purchaseOrder in xmlDoc.Descendants(ns + "purchase-order")
    select new
    {        
         PurcaseOrderNo = purchaseOrder.Element(ns + "po-number").Value,
         PurchaseDate = purchaseOrder.Element(ns + "po-date").Value,
         CustomerFullName = purchaseOrder.Element(ns + "customer-name").Value,
         ItemId = purchaseOrder.Element(ns + "po-line").Element(ns + "po-line-header").Element(ns + "item-id").Value,
    };
```

I've looked at using a foreach loop and iterating through the nodes using something like this but i need to bring back the other information for that order not just limit the results to whats in the  nodes

```
foreach (XElement po in xmlDoc.Descendants(ns + "po-line"))
{
    string ItemId = po.Element(ns + "po-line-header").Element(ns + "item-id").Value;
    string SellingPrice = po.Element(ns + "po-line-header").Element(ns + "selling-price-each").Value;                                                        
}
```

I'm looking for the best way of doing this, perhaps a combination of the two or a fresh approach is required?

So the results I need is a single line for example something like this for each purchase order where customer details will be the same but the itemId will change:

```
 customer email, po-number, ship-to name, item-id

    123456@test.com, 12345, JOHN DOH, ABC-12345
    123456@test.com, 12345, JOHN DOH, BCD-33022
```

Comment: It's not really clear what you're trying to achieve - and it doesn't help that your code is formatted so that it doesn't fit without horizontal scrolling. What result are you looking for - a single value with an `ItemIds` property with multiple results, or one result per po-line?

Comment: I want to bring back all the details within the <po-line> tags for each <purchase-order>, there can be any number of <po-line> within each, and need a way to itereate through the parent node to find these along with the other details at withing the purchase order

Comment: Yes, but how do you want that to be represented? One result per po-line, or one result per purchase-order, containing multiple sub-results in that single one?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's still not really clear what you want, but this may be all you need:

```
 // Earlier query as before...
 select new
 {

     PurcaseOrderNo = purchaseOrder.Element(ns + "po-number").Value,
     PurchaseDate = purchaseOrder.Element(ns + "po-date").Value,
     CustomerFullName = purchaseOrder.Element(ns + "customer-name").Value,
     ItemIds = purchaseOrder.Elements(ns + "po-line")
                            .Elements(ns + "po-line-header")
                            .Elements(ns + "item-id")
                            .Select(x => x.Value)
                            .ToList()
 };
```

That will give you a `List<string>` of `ItemIds` within each result.

EDIT: If you want one result per po-line, you can use:

```
var query = from order in xmlDoc.Descendants(ns + "purchase-order")
            from line in order.Elements(ns + "po-line")
            select new
            {        
                PurcaseOrderNo = order.Element(ns + "po-number").Value,
                PurchaseDate = order.Element(ns + "po-date").Value,
                CustomerFullName = order.Element(ns + "customer-name").Value,
                ItemId = line.Element(ns + "po-line-header")
                             .Element(ns + "item-id")
                             .Value
            };
```

Comment: Thanks but the second sample you have provided doesn't compile as it stands

Comment: @Paul: Fixed the typo. It would be worth making sure you *understand* the code to the extent that next time you'd be able to fix such errors yourself :)

Comment: @Paul: I *did* fix a typo - from `Element` to `Elements`. (You could have seen that by looking at the edit.) I just neglected the change from `purchaseOrder` to `order` which I'd made to keep the line length short enough.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you make classes for each object... aka:

```
public class PurchaseOrder
{
    XElement self;
    public PurchaseOrder(XElement self) { this.self = self; }

    public int Number
    {
         get { return self.Get<int>("po-number", 0); }
    }

    public POLine[] Lines
    {
         get { return _Lines ?? (_Lines = self.GetEnumerable("po-line", xe => new POLine(xe)).ToArray()); }
    }
    POLine[] _Lines;
}

public class POLine
{
    XElement self;
    public POLine(XElement self) { this.self = self; }

    public string ItemName
    {
        get { self.Get("po-line-header/item-name", string.Empty); }
    }
}
```

You can then get all the purchase orders like this:

```
XElement xfile = // load your file
PurchaseOrder[] orders = xfile.GetEnumerable("purchase-order", xe => new PurchaseOrder(xe)).ToArray();

foreach(PurchaseOrder order in orders)
{
    // do something with the order number
    int number = order.Number;

    ...

    foreach(POLine line in order.Lines)
    {
        // do something with the item name
        string itemName = line.ItemName;

        ...

    }

    ...
}
```

You can use the extension methods I make use of here: http://searisen.com/xmllib/extensions.wiki